# In python raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))

Tags: python

In python, I developed parsing program. My program recived data in website. I want to send Execl cell. but I received error message.
I want to solve myself, but I can't
I spent 7days this problem.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

    
    
    #엑셀 로그인
    
    
    load_owner_order_wb = load_workbook("order.xlsx", data_only=True)
    load_owner_order_ws = load_owner_order_wb['Sheet1']
    
    owner_source = load_owner_source_ws['A1'].value
    
    
    # html = urlopen(owner_source).read()
    html = urlopen('https://ownerclan.com/V2/product/view.php?selfcode=W13B289').read()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    
    i=1
    
    while len(load_owner_order_ws['A']) >= i:
        i = i + 1
    
    load_owner_order_ws['A%d'%i] = soup.title.string
    load_owner_order_ws['B%d'%i] = soup.find('span', class_='point_color_b2').string
    print(soup.select('#productPrice'))
    
    load_owner_order_ws['C%d'%i] = soup.select('#productPrice')
    load_owner_order_wb.save("order.xlsx")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/smart_store/owner_clan.py", line 111, in <module>
    load_owner_order_ws['C%d'%i] = soup.select('#productPrice')
  File "D:\python\smart_store\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 313, in __setitem__
    self[key].value = value
  File "D:\python\smart_store\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 216, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "D:\python\smart_store\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 199, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert [<span id="productPrice">8,100</span>] to Excel
```

Answer (score 0):

I have more experience with OpenPyXl than Beautiful Soup but the error seems to be telling you that `soup.select('#productPrice')` is returning `[<span id="productPrice">8,100</span>]` or basically a list of HTML elements (that happens to only have one value). If you want the innerHTML value of `#productPrice` then try `soup.select('#productPrice')[0].text` or `soup.find('#productPrice').text`.

I may be wrong about the `.text` part. Please refer to [Beautiful Soup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to figure out how to extract the info you want from HTML!